# Alternate url for sharepoint

Tags: alternate-access-mapping

My portal has strange behavior.

In admin page it has 3 alternate addresses:

`http://portal - default zone`
`http://portal.domain - default zone`
`http: //portal-test - default zone`

all these urls has good ping. IIS has these bindings.

But when I type "portal.domain" or "http: //portal.domain" in browser it show authentication window and redirects me to http: //portal after login\pass typed

In webTools I see that "portal.domain" return status `302 (moved temporarily)` and send me to "`http://portal`".

I have no access to DNS(only our administrators) and don't know about old SharePoint settings (it done another SharePointer who not work now).

So, the question: where can be problems and what should I check.

My aim is opening portal using "`http://portal`" when user type "`http://portal`" and using "`http://portal.domain`" when user type "`http://portal.domain`" in browser.

What should I do to correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you having 3 default zone. Ideally it should be only one. its returning http://portal because it is at first which is being mentioned as default zone.

Comment: Yep! Thank you!
I don't know why all 3 were in default zone, this portal has long story before me. I have change zone, so every url has unique zone and it work perfect. Thanks!